# Declaring an object to itself using reflection

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Not sure about the title, but here goes:

I have a class that are going to be extended, like:

```
public class A{

    public void methodThatDoesStuff(){
        //Uses AA here
    }

    protected class AA{
        //does most of the stuff here
    }
}

public class B extends A{
    public class BB extends AA{
    }
}
```

As you can see. methodThatDoesStuff uses AA, but when B is called, i want it to use BB instead.

The reason to this is that AA have some variables that are common for all the classes. But some differ. the innerClasses are JSONObjects that have @Expose variables, setters and getters.

How do i specify in the super class, which class to use?

Comment: This feels like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you really trying to do? Define an `AA` interface, and put a single arg constructor in `A` that takes it?

Comment: You are right, i will change the question

Comment: What actually replaces `Uses AA here`?

Comment: I still don't understand what you want here. Why not `public void methodThatDoesStuff(AA aa)` then your caller can pass it a `BB`.

Comment: Also maybe read more on polymorphism ;) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Comment: Still not enough information here. When you say, "uses AA", are you saying that `methodThatDoesStuff` will create an object of class AA (or BB), or are you saying that in addition to having inner class AA, class A will also have as a member an instance of class AA? In either case, is AA an actual inner class or just a nested class (that is, does AA rely on any members of class A)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify which class to use in the superclass, cause the superclass has no information for the classes, that inherit from it. Define a variable of type `AA` in the superclass and set the proper instance on runtime using constructor or setter. Demonstration:

```
public class A {
    protected AA serviceVar;

    public A() {
        this.serviceVar = new AA();
    }

    public void methodThatDoesStuff() {
        System.out.println(serviceVar);
    }

    protected class AA {
        protected String message;

        public AA() {
            message = "AA";
        }

        public String toString() {
            return message;
        }
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public B() {
        this.serviceVar = new BB();
    }

    public class BB extends AA {
        public BB() {
            this.message = "BB";
        }
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        A b = new B();
        a.methodThatDoesStuff();
        b.methodThatDoesStuff();
    }
}
```

As you can see, when you instantiate `A`, the method `methodThatDoesStuff` prints out the message depending on `AA` and when you instantiate `B` it uses `BB` instead. You use `serviceVar` where you need the functionality from `AA` or some of it's subclasses respectively. This means in your case that you use this variable in `methodThatDoesStuff`.

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough information to definitively answer this question yet, since asker hasn't adequately specified what he actually wants. At least start off explaining what you think he wants before stating things like, "You can't specify that in the superclass", which may not be true depending on how the question is interpreted.

Comment: And when you say, "You can't specify that in the superclass", exactly what "that" are you referring to?

Comment: I think it is clear enough what does he exactly want. He uses the functionality of AA in the method methodThatDoesStuff, but he wants to replace the behavior of AA with BB for the subclass instance B. As there is no static inheritance, you need to have a variable to do that and this is a way to solve the problem.

Comment: It's not clear--read my comment above. Also, depending on if it's an inner class or nested class will radically influence the "correct" architecture, since nested classes can possibly be accomplished with generics.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to do this is to define a function for creating AA objects, which subclasses can override. This allows the subclass to create objects which are a subclass of AA if that's desired.

```
public class A{

    public void methodThatDoesStuff(){
        AA aa = getAA();
        // use aa
    }

    protected class AA{
        //does most of the stuff here
    }

    // Function to create AA instances. Subclasses
    // can override this.
    protected AA getAA() {
        return new AA();
    }
}

public class B extends A{
    public class BB extends AA{
    }

    @Override
    protected AA getAA() {
       return new BB();
    }
}
```